# LT Spice - IV Curve using PWL Datapoints

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to model a PV cell using the DC sweep and I'd like to overlay my own collected data (using my real PV cell) on top of the IV curve of the PV cell model.

If I have a following table:

V vs. I

0   0.6

8.3 0.59

12.9    0.6

16  0.59

19.9    0.37

22  0

How can I plot this on top of my IV curve of the model?
See the following for my PV cell model
[image: PV Cell Model]

and

IV curve :
[image: IV Curve]

I just like to add that table and overlay on top of the IV curve that I have.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

LTspice has well known undocumented compatibility with PSpice when dealing with E and G sources and tables. You need to create a circuit symbol and subcircuit file as outlined below.

**Subcircuit containing table data:** File name: PV.sub

```
*PV table
*Subckt simulates voltage dependent current source
*Data format: input[V], output[A]
.SUBCKT XDCRTVR out+ out- in+ in-
G1 out+ out- TABLE {V(in+,in-)}=
+ 0.0  0.60
+ 8.30 0.59
+ 12.9 0.60
+ 16.0 0.59
+ 19.9 0.37
+ 22.0 0.00
.ENDS XDCRTVR
```

Each data pair is the input voltage [V] and output current [A].
The plus signs are line continuation commands.

**Schematic Symbol:** File name: PV.asy

```
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal -48 32 -48 -32
LINE Normal 64 -32 64 32
LINE Normal 64 -32 -48 -32
LINE Normal -48 32 64 32
LINE Normal -48 16 -64 16
LINE Normal -48 -16 -64 -16
LINE Normal 64 -16 80 -16
LINE Normal 64 16 80 16
TEXT 10 46 Center 2 PV Data
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR SpiceModel XdcrTVR
SYMATTR Description PV subcircuit
SYMATTR ModelFile PV.sub
PIN -64 -16 LEFT 20
PINATTR PinName in+
PINATTR SpiceOrder 3
PIN -64 16 LEFT 20
PINATTR PinName in-
PINATTR SpiceOrder 4
PIN 80 -16 RIGHT 20
PINATTR PinName out+
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN 80 16 RIGHT 20
PINATTR PinName out-
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
```

**Sample:**

[image]

Since there are only 6 data points, the curve is a bit crude. However, LTspice will do a linear interpolation of the data between points. You may want to use a maths program to do a more advanced interpolation of the data to make the graph look nicer. Note that the plotted current (-I(R1)) has a negative sign due to the way the G source is defined. You may want to reverse the output terminals.

Table data can also be used to create complex impedance subcircuits and other fun things.

Comment: G and E tables are documented, though with different syntax, in the LTspice help. https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/G_Voltage_Dependent_Current_Source.htm  https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/E_Voltage_Dependent_Voltage_Source.htm

Comment: @SteKulov The "PSpice A/D Reference Guide" has all the fun things you can do with E & G tables which LTspice happily accepts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this, but in my opinion it's easiest (especially with a low amount of points) to do the following which uses the standard `g2` symbol for a G-source.  G-source (and E-source) transfer function tables are documented within the built-in LTspice Help ([web archived version here](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/G_Voltage_Dependent_Current_Source.htm)).

[image]

If the table data is visually too long you can customize it by right-clicking it and change the font size.  Or you can right-click the symbol and remove the `X` next to that line which makes it not visible on the schematic.  And yet another thing you can try is splitting up the data across multiple lines by using the `Value2` `SpiceLine` and `SpiceLine2` attributes and making them visible for easy tweaking of the data.

---

One last tip is you don't even need to use a symbol in the first place.  You can define the G-source directly into the netlist using a SPICE directive (keyboard shortcut <kbd>S</kbd>), as shown below.

[image]

Because the same V1 is sweeping both the model and the G-source at the same time you have to plot the `Gref` and `R1` currents separately.  Because there is no symbol for `Gref` you have to right-click the plot window and select "Add Traces" to select to plot the current for it.  I modified your data points so it's easier to see both curves on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this in LT spice, but you can export the data to excel or another spreadsheet program of your choice and do that there.

There are multiple ways to export you can either print the results in the output file or directly export the data from the plot